# How to link a server root directory

Tags: directory, server, root, symlink

I need to link the root directory in my server to a parent directory.

I have this hierarchy:

```
projects (my deploy folder)
projects/myproject (my project)
repos (my repo folder with my hooks to deploy)
www (root directory)
```

The complete path in my server is:

```
/home/{user}/www
```

How to link the www folder to the folder inside projects -> projects/myproject?

I tried to use symbolic links, without success. I'm getting 403 error.

```
ln -s /home/{user}/projects/myproject /home/{user}/www
```

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE 1**

I read my question and I'm so confused about this. 
Thinking better, I don't know what is the best way to organize my server, with a blog in the root and other projects inside the same host.

How you guys organize your projects at the same host?

Now I'm thinking to put my blog inside the root folder, and the other projects inside subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

If your project directory is at /projects/myproject then your symlink could be

```
ln -s /projects/myproject/ /home/user/www
```

Note though that that will create the symlink in www, if www is the root of your server, you will effectively have the projects folder as a sub directory (/home/user/www/myproject).

If that's not what you want then you will need to remove the existing www directory and then redo the above command

Comment: I tried that and I had to delete the www folder to symlink work with my projects folder. I don't know why. But now, my root folder has a symlink to a parent directory.